# iptables : Redirect packets to another ip without nat

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn

To have multiple public ips on my home connection, i rent a VPS with few IPs, i've set a openvpn server and all the servers at my home which need a public ip, have a vpn connection and i'm doing DNAT/SNAT on the VPS to redirect the traffic destined to a specific public ip to my home server trough openvpn.

```
-A PREROUTING -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.6
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.6/32 -j SNAT --to-source xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

It work like that for more than one year on a mail server/web/ect.., it's pretty cool

I just have one issue, the incoming packet on my server is natted with the VPN server ip so i can't use access lists based on the ip, neither RBL on mail server.

Is there a way to tell iptable to redirect the traffic without doing the NAT ?

On my client, the default gateway is my vpn server so the packet will come back on the vpn in any way.

Thanks

Comment: These rules dont change the source ip of packets going into ip XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/32. Some other rule is messing you up. Post an output of iptables -t nat -vL of your VPN/Homeserver (only if you do any nat there) please. Did you do any rules with ip route / ip rule ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>If you want to change the destination but not the source just get rid of the "SNAT" rule.</s>

Sorry did not read the question carefully enough.

> let's say, my server y.y.y.y is pinging x.x.x.x, it come on my vpn server and i dnat "destination x.x.x.x to 172.17.0.6 and on my home server i get packets with source 172.17.0.1

DNAT *only* changes the destination of a connection, not the source. If you are seeing a source of 172.17.0.1 then you must have another SNAT or MASQUERADE rule that is not listed in your question that is affecting the packet. You need to remove that rule or limit it's scope so it doesn't affect the connections coming in to your home server.

If you want further help please post a complete list of iptables rules for your server, not just the ones you think are relavent.

> it go back on my vpn and get snat to go back to y.y.y.y

No, it gets reverse translated using the state tracking established when the first packet of the (psuedo-)connection was processed. iptables nat tables are only processed for the first packet of a connection.

Comment: Not really, let's say, my server y.y.y.y is pinging x.x.x.x, it come on my vpn server and i dnat "destination x.x.x.x to 172.17.0.6 and on my home server i get packets with source 172.17.0.1 and it go back on my vpn and get snat to go back to y.y.y.y

What i want to do, is ping from y.y.y.y to x.x.x.x it go on my vpn server, it's forwared to 172.17.0.6 but not natted so on my home server i get packets from y.y.y.y and not 172.17.0.1

in fact i try to get rid of the DNAT

Comment: Ohhh right i forgot to mention the -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

Removing this rule is the answer 

Thanks !